# Using contains text in page.execute_script

Tags: rspec, capybara

I am trying to click a div that contains "Some text". How can I do that using **page.execute_script**

What I tried:
page.execute_script("$div:contains('Some text')).click()")

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do that from `execute_script` - what's wrong with just

```
page.find('div', exact_text: 'Some text').click
```

?  Obviously it would be more performant if you had some classes the div should have that could be added to the CSS selector too, but either way it's better than dropping to execute_script. If you really do need to use `execute_script` (I hope you're not testing a page since it would pretty much make your test worthless) then, assuming you're using JQuery (due to the $, and non standard :contains pseudo selector in your JS), it would be something like

```
page.execute_script <<~JS
  $("div:contains('Some text')").click();
JS
```

although that is going to select all ancestor divs too, so may not click what you think it will